# Code That Copies Data and Moves It Is Really Slow

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

Over the last few weeks, work has had me build a new quote sheet. My code pulls data from the last sheet used and then generates a quote based on what you selected in that sheet (`"Data Entry"`)

I turned it over to the boss, but made note that the process I used to copy and move the data selected into the quote that is being generated is slow. It was best method I could come up with that gave consistent results and resulted nearly no errors. However it takes too long from click to quote generation for the bosses liking.

Is there a way to improve my code so it does the process faster? I am but a novice when it comes to coding (and even though I received help here, am proud of what my end product turned out to be, so shout out to everyone who has helped).

Here is the string:

```
 Dim i As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    
        
    
    For i = o To lastdtyperow
       'copies types
       Set cell = dataentry.Range("B9").Offset(i, 0)
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            quote1.Range("A13").Offset(i, 0) = cell.Value
            quote1.Range("A13").Offset(i, 0).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            quote1.Range("A13").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            quote1.Range("A13").Offset(i, 0).WrapText = True
            End If
        'copies quantities
        Set cell = dataentry.Range("C9").Offset(i, 0)
            If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
                quote1.Range("B13").Offset(i, 0) = cell.Value
                quote1.Range("B13").Offset(i, 0).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                quote1.Range("B13").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                quote1.Range("B13").Offset(i, 0).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
            End If
        'copies mfr
        Set cell = dataentry.Range("AB9").Offset(i, 0)
            If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
                quote1.Range("C13").Offset(i, 0) = cell.Value
                quote1.Range("C13").Offset(i, 0).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                quote1.Range("C13").Offset(i, 0).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
                quote1.Range("C13").Offset(i, 0).WrapText = True
                quote1.Range("C13").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            End If
        'copies cat number
        Set cell = dataentry.Range("AC9").Offset(i, 0)
            If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
                quote1.Range("D13").Offset(i, 0) = cell.Value
                quote1.Range("D13").Offset(i, 0).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                quote1.Range("D13").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                quote1.Range("D13").Offset(i, 0).WrapText = True
                
            End If
        'copies notes
        Set cell = dataentry.Range("AD9").Offset(i, 0)
            If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
                quote1.Range("E13").Offset(i, 0) = cell.Value
                quote1.Range("E13").Offset(i, 0).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                quote1.Range("E13").Offset(i, 0).WrapText = True
                quote1.Range("E13").Offset(i, 0).Font.Size = 11
                quote1.Range("E13").Offset(i, 0).Font.Name = "Calibri"
            End If
        'copies prices
        Set cell = dataentry.Range("AJ9").Offset(i, 0)
            If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
                quote1.Range("F13").Offset(i, 0) = cell.Value
                quote1.Range("F13").Offset(i, 0).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                quote1.Range("F13").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                quote1.Range("F13").Offset(i, 0).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
                quote1.Range("F13").Offset(i, 0).Font.Bold = False
            End If

    Next i
```

Relevant portions:

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'sets easy code for to last row, then move data up to next row that contains nothing
    Dim lastdtyperow, lastdqtyrow, lastqtyperow
    Dim dataentry As Worksheet, quote1 As Worksheet, data As Worksheet
    Dim typ As Range
```

What makes it so slow is it goes cell to cell, checks data, if it finds data, copy and paste it then format it. Im sure doing some method that is row based rather than cell would be faster as well as waiting to apply formatting until the end.

If required, I can post the entirety of the code to show how the sheet is being generated. If this question (I guess this could almost be a cry for help) is too ambitious, then it is what it is.

Comment: Adding `Application.Screenupdating = False` at the top of your code will likely make it faster

Comment: I have that, I failed to grab it while copying the code. Whoops. Added to OP.

Comment: Reason for the break in how I displayed the code, is between the two is some code that wipes that sheet (that process is super fast), and the the copying begins. Assumed it was not relevant, so I cut it out.

Comment: There's no need to do the formatting cell-by-cell: you can format each column at the end of the copy process.

Comment: Ok, I can make that adjustment. Shouldn't be too hard to figure that one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to minimize the Excel - VBA interactions as much as you can because Excel performs hundreds (or even thousends) of operations every time when passing control to it. Some of them (e.g. `.ScreenUpdating`) can be controlled, some of them can not.

1. A major improvement can be to copy and format blocks instead of single cells, like

   ```
   With quote1
   ' copy formulas and formats
       Range(dataentry.Cells(9, "B"), Cells(9 + lastdtyperow, "C")).Copy _
          Destination:=Range(.Cells(13, "A"), .Cells(13 + lastdtyperow, "B"))
       Range(dataentry.Cells(9, "AB"), Cells(9 + lastdtyperow, "AD")).Copy _
          Destination:=Range(.Cells(13, "C"), .Cells(13 + lastdtyperow, "E"))

    ' OR copy values only

       Range(dataentry.Cells(9, "B"), Cells(9 + lastdtyperow, "C")).Copy
       Range(.Cells(13, "A"), .Cells(13 + lastdtyperow, "B")).Pastespecial xlpastevalues

     ' copy formats only (apply format of source on destination)
       Range(dataentry.Cells(9, "B"), Cells(9 + lastdtyperow, "C")).Copy
       Range(.Cells(13, "A"), .Cells(13 + lastdtyperow, "B")).Pastespecial xlpasteformats
   ```

NB: you need to issue the 2 `.Pastespecial`s separately, but you don't need to issue the `.Copy` twice

```
   ' format data column by column
        ...
        Range(.Cells(13, "A"), .Cells(13 + lastdtyperow, "A")).WrapText = True
        ...
   End With
```

With this, you reduce Excel - VBA interactions from ~30 * lastdtyperow to ~30

2. Use `With`. It makes some performance improvement, and saves a lot of typing.
3. If you want to hide 0 values for empty cells that can show up when copying empty cells in blocks, this cellformat will replace them with empty strings:

   ```
   .NumberFormat = "#,##0;-#,##0;""""
   ```

Pay attention on the trailing quotes, you'll need quite many :)

Comment: I put this in to give it a try, and I keep getting an error. ```Compile error: Expected: list separator or )``` I have not used this particular setup, so I am unsure how it should be formatted to fix this error.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out the error. Was missing an ```)```

Comment: Now I am getting a ```Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed``` error. I am trying to fix it, but so far no luck. @AcsErno

Comment: @Tmyers Yes, 3 ) was missing. Edited the answer above. (I was too quick in answering) The last error message is most probably due to the missing ) before .wraptext.

Comment: I made that correction, but am still getting the range of object error. Ive messed with it trying to fix it, but to no avail. Any insight?

Comment: Correction, I corrected the global error by qualifying the range better in the destination ```Range(quote1.cells```, but the results were not as expected. It is copying the forumlas in the cells rather than the value the formulas are returning, as wall as all formatting with cell borders and such.

Comment: @Tmyers Edited the answer